# Cannot start sql server in antergos linux: Unit mssql-server.service has a bad unit file setting

Tags: sql-server, linux

I can no longer start sql-server on antergos linux. This is what I tried so far (following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-2017) link):

```
$ sudo systemctl status mssql-server.service
● mssql-server.service
   Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit mssql-server.service has a bad unit file setting.)
   Active: inactive (dead)

$ sudo -u mssql /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr -m SQLCMD
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: The file archive [/opt/mssql/lib/system.sfp] is invalid.  Please resolve and try again.

$ sudo ls /var/opt/mssql/log | grep .mdmp
(nothing)

$ sudo ls /var/opt/mssql/log | grep .tar.gz2 
(nothing)
```

more over, I had a look a [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Modify) document, and I tried to find the unit file of mssql service.

```
$ sudo ls -la /usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 655 ago 11 01:44 /usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service
```

Then I tried to open it with sublime-text or nano, but it seems to contain binary content, sublime-text show several columns filled with `0000`. I guess this is what systemd is talking about when it says that the service has a bad unit file setting.

Here goes some context

```
$ pacman -Q | grep sql
msodbcsql 17.2.0.1-1
mssql-server 14.0.3030.27-1
mssql-tools 17.2.0.1-1
sqlite 3.24.0-1

$ uname -a
Linux antergos 4.17.14-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 9 11:56:50 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there something else I could try before reinstalling everything?

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Doesn't look like Antergos is on the [list of officially supported Linux OSes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-2017#supportedplatforms).